# Download Custom Android Packages

Tags: android, android-studio, package

Is it possible to download custom android packages for modification.

For example if an app has

import com.name.name.packagename

Is there a way to get this package and modify it as needed?

Comment: can you be more specific? In some cases this is easy (even "common") but in others, it's nearly impossible..

Comment: @Jim thanks for the reply. What i mean I bought an open-source app but I realized that some packages are imported from the main server of the developer while I need to download them and load from our servers.

Comment: So you don't need to modify the code, only the source location? And can you access those packages now? And are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I wanna modify the code so I wanna download them from the source location and import locally rather remotely I mean instead of using 3rd party servers I'll use ours. And yes I am using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Of course! After you download the app, use File Explore to access the package as well as its contents. An example of navigating via a directory is as follows:

Desktop --> AndroidStudioProjects --> PackageName --> mobile --> src --> main --> java --> com --> name --> name --> packagename --> **the app's java files**

Comment: thanks for the reply your answer works in case I'm importing all the files locally however some of the files are imported from remote servers therefore I need to know if I can download them to be loaded from our servers

Answer (score 0):

So since you have access to the source code, and you want to "make them available on your servers" then this is likely your solution:

In your `gradle` file you probably have specified repositories and paths to this code. You can bundle the code as an `aar` (library) on a local server and then point gradle to that location to download (by specifying the files location of the `aar`). You could also host your own repo (nexus or whatever) and include that repo in your gradle settings.

Also, be sure to clear your gradle cache when you do this, or else it may not find your "new" files.

There are easier ways than hosting it on a server - such forking the repo locally and including it as a module, or do the fork and then build an `aar` locally that you include in gradle.

Hope that helps.